# is it an issue to use a while loop inside a for loop? In particular since the for loop only iterates forward?

Tags: python, loops

I am answering the following Leetcode question: https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-all-adjacent-duplicates-in-string-ii/

Here is a simple example;

```
Input: s = "deeedbbcccbdaa", k = 3
Output: "aa"
Explanation: 
First delete "eee" and "ccc", get "ddbbbdaa"
Then delete "bbb", get "dddaa"
Finally delete "ddd", get "aa"
```

Here is my code:

```
def removeDuplicates(s: str, k: int) -> str:
    dup = [k * i for i in "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm"]
    dup_index = []
    nextt_s = ""

    for duplicates in dup:
        while duplicates in s:

            #identify index of the duplicated characters in the input 
            for index in range(s.index(duplicates), s.index(duplicates) + len(duplicates)):
                dup_index.append(index)

            for i, e in enumerate(s):
                if i not in dup_index:
                    nextt_s += e
            s = nextt_s

    return s
```

For some reason when I execute the above for the input "deeedbbcccbdaa"; it gets stuck and goes crazy when I `print dup_index or nextt_s`. I think there is something wrong with the loop.

My intention with the `while loop` is to continue iterating through the input until there are no duplicated characters left in it. And after each iteration I will have removed the duplicated characters and the new string will be called next_s

I can see one issue with using the for loop then while loop in the way it is; in that after the original input gets shortened, and say the for loop is at "hhh" and the shortened string becomes say "bbbfjfdshf" ; then "bbb" will never be reached again, because the for loop only moves forward.

Answer (score 0):

```
def removeDuplicates(s: str, k: int) -> str:
    dup = [k * i for i in "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm"]
    changes=True
    while changes:
        changes=False
        for duplicates in dup:
            while duplicates in s: 
                changes=True
                #s=s.replace(duplicates,"") or
                s=s[:s.index(duplicates)]+s[s.index(duplicates)+k:]
    return s
```

you could make it like this.
find the index of the duplicate and take all characters from left and all characters from right side of string (or use replace)
Put your code inside a loop untill one loop ends with no changes in string s